# News Scrolling Text in Python

Tags: python, scroll, news-ticker

I want to write a small program that displays auto-scrolling news ticker text from left to right  (with Tkinter?),or at least some GUI.

The text should come from a text .txt file.

I am still a beginner in Python and can't really grasp how to do this? Like how to control the timings from each line to show up etc?

Would a loop calling each line be the right way to do this?

Or how would you approach this? All help/links will be very appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a program using Tkinter to scroll text in a box.  See [1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm) and [2](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) regarding options for `label()`; see [3](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm) about the `after()` method.

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
deli = 100           # milliseconds of delay per character
svar = tk.StringVar()
labl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=svar, height=10 )

def shif():
    shif.msg = shif.msg[1:] + shif.msg[0]
    svar.set(shif.msg)
    root.after(deli, shif)

shif.msg = ' Is this an alert, or what? '
shif()
labl.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used two different libraries with Python so far:

[PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) - wraps Qt and is in my opinion a nice Gui library but then I haven't used any absolute positioning like you want to, but I can't see how that should be any major problem.

[PyGame](http://www.pygame.org) - As you've guessed it's main purpose is games but what you want to do should be simple to do.

Go through a couple of tutorials with the library of your choice and your task shouldn't be any problem at all. For what you want to do I think that PyGame would be the easiest.